# SSRS Date time picker: allow user to pick the time component

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services

I want to use a date-time picker to select a date *as well as the* time component. The calender allows me to pick a date but there's no possibility to choose the a specific time.

I want to choose a start and end time, to select a subset out of lot of a data.

Comment: can you please tell me what you have tried.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue in my current project. My solution is to add a field for the date (type of date/time) and a field for the time. The time field will show a drop down list containing the 24 hours text for users to select (refer to attach screenshot below).

[image]

The steps to create the dropdown list is simple:

1. Open the propery of the time parameter of the report
2. Select Available Values (refer to attached screenshot below)

[image]

3. Select Specify values and add values to represent the 24 hours.

Please note, you can also set the available values from a query.

In addition, the stored procedure where the report data are retrieved should convert the date and time passed from the report to datetime type to get it work. Below shows a sample:

```
@StartDateTime = CONVERT(datetime, convert(nvarchar, @StartDate) + 
          ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(12), @starttime))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure we have all found a way around this by now, however here is my solution.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ssrs].[Params_GetTimeTable]
(
    @hr_from int = 0,
    @hr_to int = 24,
    @min_interval int = 15
)
AS
BEGIN
-- Internal Variables
declare @hr int = @hr_from
declare @min int = 0
declare @timetable table
(
    hhmm varchar(5)
)

-- Populate the @timetable
    while @hr < @hr_to
    begin
        while @min < 60
        begin
            insert into @timetable(hhmm)
            select 
                case 
                    when @hr < 10 then '0' + cast(@hr as varchar(2)) + ':' + case when @min < 10 then '0' + cast(@min as varchar(2)) else cast(@min as varchar(2)) end
                    else cast(@hr as varchar(2)) + ':' + case when @min < 10 then '0' + cast(@min as varchar(2)) else cast(@min as varchar(2)) end
                end
            set @min = @min + @min_interval
        end
        set @hr = @hr + 1
        set @min = 0
    end

--  Add a finishing time to the output table
    insert into @timetable(hhmm)
    select 
        case 
            when @hr < 10 then '0' + cast(@hr as varchar(2)) + ':00'
            else cast(@hr as varchar(2)) + ':00'
        end

-- Return the output
 select hhmm from @timetable

END
```

Test the result by:

```
EXEC [ssrs].[Params_GetTimeTable] 0, 24, 15
```

Output :

```
hhmm
00:00
00:15
00:30
00:45
01:00
01:15
...
23:00
23:15
23:30
23:45
24:00
```

Comment: Is there any option to get up to 23:58 time? I tried, yet it won't allow since it is in Int value

Comment: I'm late to the party but I used this SQL to generate drop down in SSRS. I had an error  when selecting 24:00 so I changed the last case to insert 23:59 instead of 24. "insert into @timetable(hhmm) values ('23:59')"

Answer (score 1):

With the standard SSRS calendar picker, after you have selected a date, you can click in the textbox and manually enter the time value next to the selected date.  I know this is not very user intuitive, but it does work. 
I have the same problem, and am looking for a more user friendly solution, but this is all I can come with so far.

Answer (score 0):

I use this SQL which generates times every 15mins between 9:00 and 21:00, people is just any table with at least enough rows i.e. 12 or 24.

```
select time1
from
(
  select hr || ':' || mm time1
  from  
  (
    select  '09' hr
    from  dual
    union
    select  cast(rownum + 9 as varchar(2)) hr 
    from  people 
    where rownum < 12
    order by hr
  )hr,
  (
    select  '00' mm
    from  dual
    union
    select  '15' mm
    from  dual
    union
    select  '30' mm
    from  dual
    union
      select  '45' mm
    from  dual
  )mm
  union
  (
  select  '21:00' time1
  from  dual
  )
)T1
order by time1
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this as an integer parameter then you can add the number of minutes to whatever date is selected

```
DECLARE @interval INT = 15
;WITH cteM AS (
  SELECT 0 M UNION ALL
  SELECT M+@interval FROM cteM
  WHERE M+@interval <= 59
), 
cteH AS (
  SELECT 0 H UNION ALL
  SELECT H+1 FROM cteH
  WHERE H+1 < 24
)
SELECT
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(cteH.H AS varchar(2)), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(cteM.M AS varchar(2)), 2) Label,
    cteH.H*60 + cteM.M Value
FROM cteM CROSS JOIN cteH
```