# SSRS : Parameter as Time Picker

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

In my SSRS reports, I have a datetime parameter but the calendar picker doesn't allow me to input time.

Is there a way / hack for me to input a time picker as my input ?

I am running on SQL Server 2008R2 Standard Edition.

Thanks.

Comment: Something similar If i get the question correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134334/ssrs-date-time-picker-allow-user-to-pick-the-time-component

Comment: I am using this method currently but I am looking for a picker just like windows where you have +/- button.